# How to get hold on calendar dijit for xp:dateTimeHelper to set firstdayoftheweek attribute?

Tags: dojo, xpages, dijit.calendar

I have set up a datepicker helper for an inputfield for my xpages form:

```
<xp:inputText id="agenda">
<xp:dateTimeHelper></xp:dateTimeHelper>
</xp:inputText>
```

I want to set the firstdayoftheweek attribute for the dojo calendar dijit but when I choose

```
var target = dojo.byId("#{id:agenda}")
```

I get hold of the input element

if I try

```
var target = dijit.byId("#{id:agenda}")
```

I get the hold on the same input element.

SO how should I get hold of the generated calendar dijit and then set the value for firstdayoftheweek  to 1 (Monday?)

Comment: you are using parentheses instead of curly braces

Comment: you are correct. I edited the text for the question. still remains how to get hold of the calendar widget, not the input field

Comment: Im guessing it will use Monday as first day of the week if you set the language of the web page to e.g. Swedish

Comment: yes it does, but if the application does not support swedish and only your calendar is in Swedish it is just weird

Comment: If the application is in english then set it to an english locale that uses Monday as the first day of week